# Firing a sound with a timer in a backgroundworker, wp7 phone app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, backgroundworker

I am hitting a wall and have come here hoping you guys can help me out with the following:

I am designing a wp7 app where I am having sounds fire off periodically (every 700 ms). I want these sounds to play on another thread than the UI thread. Thus, I cannot use a `dispatch timer` because the UI thread will be heavily used in the meantime while these sounds fire.

In looking at this problem, I made a `backgroundworker` with a `Thread.Sleep(700)` command. This works, but as one may expect it can take longer than 700 ms to fire off a sound. So sometimes I hear delays.

So I turn to you guys -- How can I get as close to a firing of a sound every 700 ms in a `backgroundworker` or another thread? Is a `Timer` a wise idea?

Here is some code to better illustrate:

```
    private void RunBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker ();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartSounds); 

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    public void StartSounds(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (currentsoundchoice = 0; currentsoundchoice <= max; currentsoundchoice ++)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                currentsoundchoice = max + 1; //just to ensure it stops.
            }
            else
            {
                Time_Tick();
                if (max == 12)
                    currentsoundchoice = -1; //repeats the loop when it reaches max.

            }

        }
    }


    void Time_Tick()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(700);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

        switch (sounds)
            case 0: //code 
                    break;
            // ETC, So forth.......
    }
```

I heard that using a Timer is also a good way to go about this, but is it possible to run a timer in a backgroundworker, and if so, how would it be structured? More importantly, would it allow me to get as close to the 700 ms firing time I desire without any audible delays?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is the wrong choice here. It is designed to allow you to perform expensive work on a background thread and then synchronize the results back to the UI. You do not need any synchronization. Moreover, you need the work to occur at a regular interval - not as a one-off task.

A `Timer` would be much more suited. It would allow you to run your logic every 700ms and to remove the nasty `Thread.Sleep()` call you have in your current code. The `Timer` will use a background thread just like `BackgroundWorker` does.

Note, however, that it can only guarantee that it won't run *before* 700ms has elapsed. If you're absolutely hammering the device, for example, it may struggle to run your code on a regular interval and you may notice lag.

Comment: Thank you. I have thus switched to the timer and it works very well for what I am doing. Much appreciated for the clarification.